How to add users to a particular repository using API
I am struggling in going through the API documentation for Azure devops on how to add a user to a particular repo using Rest API with read and write access to a git repository. Please guide me on this.
For Example: There are 3 Repositories. I want to restrict access to other two repositories via API.
I fetched the namespaceId and used access control entitlement APIs nothing helped

Hi there, Welcome to SO. May I know you would expect to add a user to a Project security group like [ProjectA]\Contributors or a custom team with access to a repo?

Hi, I am new to DevOps. I have a list of user emails with me. I have created a project, Repositories and branches using the API calls. Now I just want to add users to a particular repository with read and write permission. I have the namespaceId for their access control.

There are no actions to add users to a particular repository. Users access to a repo can be organized by access levels and security groups. Are they all on or above the Basic access level? Are they added into the DevOps organization already?

Hi Alvin, yes they are added to the organization with default Project Team / Contributor access but they should not be able to access all the repos excluding one.

By default the members of [Project]\Contributors group has access to all repos in this project. What is your actual expectation in this post? To deny the users' access to all repos except 1 specific repo? Please clarity in your original post.

Yes Alvin, I want the user to access only a particular repository but not the other repos.

@Hi Jai, Have you got a chance to test my script below to call API and restrict repo access for a group of users? Hope it can help resolve your query in this post. Thx.

Based on the further discussions, the actual requirement is to allow users' access to one single repo in a project and prevent the access to other repos in this project. For this, you may try the sample PowerShell script below, which will Deny All repositories Contribute permission for [PrjectA]\Contributors group and Allow Repo1 Contribute permission for [PrjectA]\Contributors group.
$organization = "YourADOOrgName"
$project = "ProjectA"
$groupName = "Contributors"
$allowRepo = "Repo1"

$MyPat = 'xxxxx'
$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$MyPat"))
$headers = @{
    'Authorization' = 'Basic ' + $B64Pat
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
}

# Get projects GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects?api-version=7.1-preview.4
$projectsURL = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/projects?api-version=7.1-preview.4"
$projects = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $projectsURL -Method Get -Headers $headers
$projectA = $projects.value | Where-Object { $_.name -eq "$project" }
$projectAId = $projectA.id
Write-Host "The id of $project is $projectAId"

# Get repos GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=7.1-preview.1
$reposURL = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
$repos = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $reposURL -Method Get -Headers $headers
$repo = $repos.value | Where-Object { $_.name -eq "$allowRepo" }
$repoId = $repo.id
Write-Host "The id of $allowRepo is $repoId"

# Get group identity GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/identities?searchFilter=General&filterValue=Project Collection Valid Users&queryMembership=None&api-version=7.2-preview.1
$groupIdsURL = "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/identities?searchFilter=General&filterValue=[$project]\$groupName&queryMembership=None&api-version=7.2-preview.1"
$groupIds = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $groupIdsURL -Method Get -Headers $headers
$groupId = $groupIds.value | Where-Object { $_.providerDisplayName -eq "[$project]\$groupName" }
$groupDescriptor = $groupId.descriptor
Write-Host "The descriptor for group [$project]\$groupName is $groupDescriptor"

# All security namespaces GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/securitynamespaces?api-version=7.2-preview.1
$namespacesURL = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/securitynamespaces?api-version=7.2-preview.1"
$namespaces = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $namespacesURL -Method Get -Headers $headers
$namespaces |  ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Out-File "C:\Users\Alvin\Desktop\namespaces.json"
$namespaceGitRepos = $namespaces.value | Where-Object { $_.displayName -eq "Git Repositories" }
$namespaceIdGitReposContribute = $namespaceGitRepos.actions | Where-Object { $_.displayName -eq "Contribute" }
$namespaceIdGitReposContributeBit = $namespaceIdGitReposContribute.bit
$namespaceIdGitRepos = $namespaceGitRepos.namespaceId
Write-Host "The id for namespace Git Repositories is $namespaceIdGitRepos"
Write-Host "The bit for permission Contribute in namespace Git Repositories is $namespaceIdGitReposContributeBit"

# Access Control Entries - Set Access Control Entries POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/accesscontrolentries/{securityNamespaceId}?api-version=7.2-preview.1
$contributeACEURL = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/accesscontrolentries/${namespaceIdGitRepos}?api-version=7.2-preview.1"

# Deny All repositories Contribute permission for [PrjectA]\Contributors group
$contributeDenyACEBody = @{
    "token" = "repoV2/$projectAId"
    "merge" = $true
    "accessControlEntries" = @(
        @{
            "descriptor" = "$groupDescriptor"
            "allow" = 0
            "deny" = $namespaceIdGitReposContributeBit
            "extendedInfo"= @{
                "effectiveAllow" = 0
                "effectiveDeny" = $namespaceIdGitReposContributeBit
                "inheritedAllow" = 0
                "inheritedDeny" = $namespaceIdGitReposContributeBit
            }
        }
    )
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $contributeACEURL -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $contributeDenyACEBody 

# Allow Repo1 Contribute permission for [PrjectA]\Contributors group
$contributeAllowACEBody = @{
    "token" = "repoV2/$projectAId/$repoId"
    "merge" = $true
    "accessControlEntries" = @(
        @{
            "descriptor" = "$groupDescriptor"
            "allow" = $namespaceIdGitReposContributeBit
            "deny" = 0
            "extendedInfo"= @{
                "effectiveAllow" = $namespaceIdGitReposContributeBit
                "effectiveDeny" = 0
                "inheritedAllow" = $namespaceIdGitReposContributeBit
                "inheritedDeny" = 0
            }
        }
    )
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $contributeACEURL -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $contributeAllowACEBody


Once tested working, you may spread to other permissions like Read and set permissions for another group of users like Readers.

This is awesome, Thanks ! Alvin
